# constexpr guard clause does not compile

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, if-constexpr, guard-clause

I wanted to add a constexpr guard clause in my code in order to avoid unnecessary indentation, but ran into this issue.

This compiles:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void inc(T& t) {
    if constexpr (!std::is_arithmetic_v<T>) {
        return;
    } else {
        ++t;
    }
}

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    std::string s = "bar";
    inc(i);
    inc(s);
    std::cout << "Success!";
}
```

Whereas this does not:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void inc(T& t) {
    if constexpr (!std::is_arithmetic_v<T>) {
        return;
    }
    ++t;
}

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    std::string s = "bar";
    inc(i);
    inc(s);
    std::cout << "Success!";
}
```

Compiler error:

```
main.cpp:9:5: error: cannot increment value of type 'std::string'
    ++t;
    ^ ~
main.cpp:17:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'inc<std::string>' requested here
    inc(s);
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Why won't this work?

To clarify: I'm writing a googletest TYPED_TEST to test my code for various types, but some tests requires the type to be incrementable. I thought to add a constexpr guard clause to skip types that does not support that operation.

Comment: The second `++t;` is not a part of `if consexpr` statement, thus is not discarded from being compiled for `std::string`.

Comment: Would you expect `std::string s; return; ++s;` to compile?

Comment: *to avoid unnecessary indentation* You might want to use function template specializations with `std::enable_if` or concepts.

Comment: It is not clear why you believe `++t` should "work" when `t` is a `std::string`.  The code is unreachable, but you are still asking the compiler to make sense of that line.

Comment: @273K I'm writing a googletest TYPED_TEST to test my code for various types, but some tests requires the type to be incrementable. I don't see how I'd template specialize a TYPED_TEST.

Comment: @Drew Dormann No, I don't expect ++t to "work" when t is a std::string. That's why I added the guard clause...

Comment: @FredrikEnetorp your question seems to be "Why won't this work?"  It doesn't work because `++t` is **not** in any guard clause.  It is compiled regardless of the type of `t`.  Your example that compiles _does_ have `++t` in a guard clause.

Comment: @DrewDormann The point of a guard clause is to exit early, and since it's constexpr it would make sense for the compiler to discard the rest if the clause triggers. Yes, this is obviously not the case, but is there a good reason for why it doesn't?

Comment: *but is there a good reason for why it doesn't?* -- The reason is that C++ doesn't work this way.  An unguarded piece of code will be compiled.

Comment: *is there a good reason for why it doesn't?* Standard cannot require compiler to analyse every possible path through the function to see if it is valid to remove code. It can be only allowed as optimisation. And compiler cannot optimise away an error, so...

Comment: C++ code must make sense.  Even in a function that you're not calling.  Even after a return statement.  If you typed it, it must follow the rules of the language.

Comment: "The point of a guard clause is to exit early" No it is not. The point of a guard clause is to guard a piece of code inside. It is not a point of the guard clause to guard a piece of code that is not inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `if constexpr` branch that is taken and unconditionally exits the function doesn't prevent a check of the validity of substituted expressions following the `if constexpr` statement, for the same reason that a simple unconditional `return` statement doesn't prevent the same check.

Of course, theoretically, if there is a statement that unconditionally exits from a function one could argue that it doesn't matter what comes after that statement and that it doesn't matter either whether substitution of template arguments results in a valid expression.

However, there is no such rule. A statement following an unconditional exit is still checked for validity after substitution in the same way any other non-discarded statement is checked.

If there was such a rule, it would need to define exactly when validity of statements isn't checked. In general it is undecidable (in the sense of computability theory) whether a statement in a function is reachable. So at best you'd need to specify special cases such as a separate `return` statement in the same scope or a nested `if constexpr` branch as condition for the special rule to apply.

But then you'd have a weird difference depending on the exact form in which the function is written. I don't think adding this complexity would be beneficial overall. Also, there are other effects of just having the substituted statements, even if they are unreachable, e.g. regarding odr-use and implicit instantiation of template specializations, which would then also have different behaviour depending on the exact syntactical form of the function body.

There is also no need for such a rule, because it can in practice always be achieved explicitly with a `if constexpr`. In your case the condition can be negated and then `++t` can be placed into the true-branch to simplify the syntax a bit. Otherwise, the `else` branch can be taken. That this requires some extra punctuation and indentation is unlikely to be good enough reason to add complexity to the language. C++ isn't known to be very concise in syntax anyway.